# Frame rate independent gravity

Tags: java, frame-rate, gravity, delta

I am having an issue with gravity varying severely with frame rate shifts.  When I run at 160 fps, my player jumps a few meters in the air then falls, but at about 10 fps, my player jumps half a meter then falls.  My code for gravity is as follows:

```
public void fall(long delta) {
    float increase = acceleration * ((delta) / 1000000000); //changes delta time (nanoseconds) to seconds
    if(player.y + velocity + increase < -1.15f) {
        if(velocity + inc < terminal_velocity) {
            velocity += inc;
        }
        player.y += velocity;
    }else{
        player.y = -1.15f;
        velocity = 0;
    }
}
```

And where I call it:

```
while(!close_request) {
        now = getTime();
        int delta = getDelta(now);

        player.fall(delta);

        ........other functions.........

    }
```

I thought implementing the delta would keep the player from changing velocity too fast or too slow, but it actually made it a bit worse.  I think this is due to the fact that as the time between frames increases, so does the increase in velocity which causes the player to fall abnormally fast.  This comes from the fact that as the FPS increases, the player jumps much, much higher.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
player.y += velocity;
```

which fails to take into account that *velocity* is "distance divided by time".

You're correctly modelling acceleration:

```
v = u + a * t   // v = current velocity, a = acceleration, t = time
```

but not distance, which for small enough `delta` is:

```
delta_s = v * delta_t
```

You need to multiply `velocity` by `delta` before adding it to to the position.

Answer (score 2):

You are not modeling the physics correctly. Assuming dt is small enough this will provide a "good enough" approximation.

```
curV     // current velocity
accel    // global acceleration constant
terminal // terminal velocity for object
dt       // delta time in seconds

fall(dt):
    deltaV = accel * dt                  // Change in velocity in a vacuum
    newV = curV + deltaV                 // New velocity 
    if (newV < terminal) newV = terminal // Don't exceed downwards terminal velocity
    y = y + dt * (curV+newV)/2           // New position
    curV = newV                          // Save new velocity as current
```

It ignores the complexities of things like acceleration decreasing as you approach terminal velocity.  The big difference between this and yours is the appearance of `dt` *twice*, once in calculating `deltaV` and then again in calculating the new vertical position.

Comment: Thanks! This is the same thing as the Alnitak's post but not as plain out.  Still a very good answer so +1!